# Once Ethereum moves to proof of stake, are most rewards coming from validation duties or from proposing blocks?

Tags: validators, block-reward, attestations

I am aware that after The Merge Ethereum will move to proof of stake.

There will no longer be any miners. However, validators may get rewards not just for proposing a block, but also due to enforcing Ethereum network rules.

But which of the two is a more important source of eth from a validator perspective?

Answer (score 1):

The rewards structure for validators after the merge is mostly the same. They get their base rewards for securing the network which include:

- **Attesting correctly**. Every epoch, each validator is expected to correctly select the source, head and target of the blockchain by voting on them. They get rewards for each correct vote.
- **Proposing a block** when selected for a slot.
- **Participating in a sync committee** when selected for that duty.

After the merge, they will also get rewards for:

- **Including transactions** in their block when selected for proposing a block in a slot. For each transaction they include, they will get the associated tip (transaction fees minus fees that are burned).
- **MEV value** they can extract from the transactions they include in their block. [Maximal extractable value (MEV)](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/mev/) refers to the maximum value that can be extracted from block production in excess of the standard block reward and gas fees by including, excluding, and changing the order of transactions in a block. Extracting MEV is optional.

The only constant source of rewards is from attestations because that is a regular duty. Being selected to propose a block or participating in a sync committee is a random event. There can be months between when a validator is selected to propose a block or participate in a sync committee.

The base reward for proposing a block can be 10 times the amount of attesting but since it's happening so infrequently, it does not make it more important than attesting in terms of rewards.

However, after the merge, blocks are also going to be worth a lot more because of the tips and MEV you can get from them. There is a wild variance of possible values you can get for proposing a block after the merge. In a time of high gas fees with a lot of potential MEV value, a validator could make more than 40 ETH by proposing a single block. If you are the lucky validator selected for that slot, your proposal is likely going to be worth more than all the other rewards you would have obtained by doing your regular duties. If you are a validator that is very unlucky and you don't get to propose many blocks and the blocks that you propose have a low tip and MEV value, your regular duties are likely to give you more rewards.

There are various proposals and solutions to *smooth out* those big spikes in terms of rewards and distribute them more equally over time and over a big pool of validators. Nothing is built in the base protocol for that, but there are potentially external solutions that could be applied.